# Selenium testing local string

Tags: selenium

Instead of getting the HTML from a server, I already have the HTML string in memory, and I want to use Selenium to check its content.  Is that possible?

Comment: Are you serving the html locally?  If so you can point your browser to localhost using selenium.

Comment: I think you are looking for Nokogiri gem. Are you planning to do some screen scrapping? I have been working with html files locally, stripping them off the unnecessary chars and saving them as strings or local text files.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate your local html file as a string or as a local txt file if you prefer.

Here is how to do it in Ruby:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

# *** open a URL as a string or as a local txt file 
# *** strip the file out of unnecessary html tags and encode chars ***

$url = driver.current_url    
$txt_file = open($url)


$raw_contents = $txt_file.read    
$html = Nokogiri::HTML(CGI.unescapeHTML($raw_contents)).content
#here we strip the web page fetched out of all hmtl tags and encoded chars


$txt_file = File.new('c:\ruby193\bin\web-content\web_read.txt', "w") 
#web_read.txt should now contain a stripped, pure txt file

$txt_file.write($html)
$txt_file.close
```